# Execute query at MongoLab site

Tags: sql, mongodb, mlab

I'm trying to run this query at MongoLab but get the error as shown in the attached image:

```
var lastWeek = new Date();
lastWeek.setDate(lastWeek.getDate() -7);
db.messages.find({ "rep_header.share_date_2.$date": {$gte: lastWeek}});
```

What I'm missing here? Where those quotes goes to?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MongoLab UI only accepts strict JSON queries (no scripting, in other words). If you need to dynamically generate the value for `lastWeek`, you'll need to run that script in the mongo shell.